# Mark top entries of subsets in R with tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyr, purrr

I'd like to mark my first top-ranked value with a marker using the tidyverse - if possible.

Assume the following data

```
test = tibble(group=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), values = c(1,2,3,4,7,6,5,2))
```

I'd now like to mark the first top values, which would be the values 3 and 4 for group 1 and 7 and 6 for group 2, yielding:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  group values marker
  <dbl>  <dbl> <lgl> 
1     1      1 FALSE 
2     1      2 FALSE 
3     1      3 TRUE
4     1      4 TRUE 
5     2      7 TRUE 
6     2      6 TRUE 
7     2      5 FALSE 
8     2      2 FALSE
```

I thought about ranking them and than doing a comparison to get the boolean values or utilizing purrr but I could not figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After grouping by 'group', either `rank` the 'values' check the `sort`ed 'n' `tail` elements are `%in%` the `rank`ed ones to create a logical `vector`

```
library(tidyverse)
test %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(marker = dense_rank(values), 
          marker = marker %in% tail(sort(marker), 2))
```

Or directly use `order`, `%in%` on the `tail`

```
test %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(marker = values %in% tail(values[order(values)], 2))
```

Or

```
test %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(marker = dense_rank(values) > n()-2)
```

---

Or it can be done in a single line with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[order(values), marker := values %in% tail(values, 2), group]
```

---

Or another option is after grouping by 'group', get the `top_n` rows (`n` - specified as 2, `wt` as 'values'), `right_join` with the original dataset after creating a 'marker' column of 'TRUE's, and then `replace` the `NA` elements with `FALSE`

```
test %>%
   group_by(group) %>% 
   top_n(2, values) %>%
   mutate(marker = TRUE) %>%
   right_join(test) %>%
   mutate(marker = replace_na(marker, FALSE))
```

Comment: well, the top_n functions seems helpful for future use, but the version without joining looks better.